# Grouping globs of data incrementally

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data set that consists of contiguous chunks of non-zero numeric values separated by contiguous chunks of zeros. I want to incrementally group the contiguous chunks of non-zero values (ala `dplyr::group_by`), then drop the zeros. I've figured it out, but I'm using a helper function with a `for` loop that is rather inefficient and very inelegant. (Note that this is a time-series dataset so order must be maintained).

Is there a more elegant way to do this using `dplyr` or `data.table` (or vectorize)?

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(var1 = c(0, 0, 2.5, 3.4, 5.7, 2.1, 0, 0, 0, 16.3, 14.9, 0, 0, 129.1, 764.3, 345.5, 0))

myfun <- function(x){
  n <- 1
  mygroup <- 1
  for(i in 2:length(x)){
    if(x[[i]] == 0 && x[[i-1]] != 0){
      n <- n + 1
    }
    mygroup[[i]] <- n
  }
  mygroup
}

df1 <- df %>% 
  mutate(group = myfun(df[[1]])) %>% 
  filter(var1 != 0) %>%
  group_by(group)
```

Here is the desired output

```
> df1
   var1 group
1   2.5     1
2   3.4     1
3   5.7     1
4   2.1     1
5  16.3     2
6  14.9     2
7 129.1     3
8 764.3     3
9 345.5     3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df %>%
    mutate(group = cumsum((var1 == 0))) %>%
    dplyr::filter(var1 != 0) %>%
    mutate(group = cumsum(!duplicated(group)))
```

Answer (score 2):

One way using `dplyr` could be:

```
df %>%
 mutate(group = with(rle(var1 == 0), rep(seq_along(lengths), lengths))) %>%
 filter(var1 != 0) %>%
 mutate(group = cumsum(!duplicated(group)))

   var1 group
  <dbl> <int>
1   2.5     1
2   3.4     1
3   5.7     1
4   2.1     1
5  16.3     2
6  14.9     2
7 129.      3
8 764.      3
9 346.      3
```

Or:

```
df %>%
 mutate(group = with(rle(var1 == 0), rep(seq_along(lengths), lengths))) %>%
 filter(var1 != 0) %>%
 mutate(group = dense_rank(group))
```